# Need to compare dates in SSRS

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Pretty new to SSRS and I have a datetime field in my SSRS report "Fields!Call_Attempt.Value" that I want to affect another text box in my report. If this field is between two specific times I want this box to return a unicode checkmark.

So my code looks something like this

```
 =iif(Fields!Call_Attempt.Value < 12:00:00
 and Fields!Call_Attempt.Value >= 8:00:00, "✓", "")
```

Obviously this code doesn't work. I just haven't been able to find the logic in SSRS to compare datetimes...

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a calculated field to the data set with the following expression:

```
=IIf(Hour(Fields!Call_Attempt.Value)<12 and Hour(Fields!Call_Attempt.Value)>=8, "x", "")
```

I'm assuming that you have a table in the report, and the one of the cells in that table is the date/time field.

- You could add a calculated field to the data set with the check/unchecked value you want, then include that field in the table.
- You could change the properties of the table cell and include the above expression as the value for the cell.  (Right click the cell, choose Properties. The cell value is under the General tab and you can put the expression there.)
- More than likely, you'll want to include multiple columns in the table, one with a formatted date/time and another with the checkbox.  In that case, you can add a column to the table, then merge the header cells and change borders so that it looks like one column with some of the values checked.

In summary, you could use the above expression to return whatever you need for anything in the table cell: the value, the tooltip, the font, the text color, the fill color, the action, the alignment...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for but it doesn't seem to work. It's not displaying anything in the box even when the time is between those two numbers.

Comment: Nevermind I fatfingered something. Thank you! You were very helpful